# jquery validator highlight method

Tags: jquery, validation

how does "element.form" work in following code found in jquery validator:

```
  highlight: function (element, errorClass, validClass) {
     $(element.form).find(".field-container .field") .addClass(errorClass);
  }
```

Comment: this may give some light. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846643/how-jquery-validation-code-works 
and jQuery validator documentation should explained this enough. https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/